# Is the statement: "∃m ∈ℤ, ∀n ∈ℤ,m=n+5" true or false?

Tags: logic

Is the statement: "∃m ∈ ℤ, ∀n ∈ ℤ,m=n+5" true or false?

This was recently asked on a test and according to the solutions, the correct answer is true.

Solutions also say that the worded translation is:

*"there exists an integer m such that for all intergers n, m=n+5"*

My friend argues that it the statement is asking if one integer could statisfy the equation for all integers (which is false), whereas my teacher, myself, and peers cant really explain why his understanding isn't correct.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The answer should be false.

Such $m$ can't exists, if such $m$ exists, let $n=m$, then we have $m=m+5$ and we get $0=5$ which is a contradiction.

Note that if we flip the quantifier, that is

$$\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, m=n+5$$

would be true, as once $m$ is chosen, we can pick $n=m-5$ to make the equality holds.

Comment: It would be good to add that if the quantifiers were switched, giving $\forall n \in \Bbb Z \exists m \in \Bbb z m=n+5$ is true because $n$ is chosen before $m$.  The solution set is wrong on the question as asked.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The order of quantifiers is something a lot of people have trouble with.  It seems to me reading the statement aloud in English can help.  I like to emphasize it.  +1